# Инициализация свойства конструктором по умолчанию

Tags: c#

Есть такой код

```
using System;
class a
{
    int x;
    public int Val { get { return x; } set { Console.WriteLine("OK"); x = value; } }
}
class Demo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        a A = new a();
    }
}
```

Конструктор по умолчанию должен инициализировать свойство `Val` дефолтным значением равным нулю. И соответственно для этого (по крайней мере я так думаю) вызывается аксессор `set`, и следовательно на консоли должа быть надпись `OK`. Но этого нет. Почему так происходит. Если написать свой конструктор, тогда нормально.

Comment: потому что конструктор инициализирует не свойство, а поле, кстати, в данном случае - свойство вообще не вызывается в конструкторе, так как свойство это две функции никак не привязанные к чему-нибудь их нет смысла вызывать в конструкторе.

Comment: Конструктор по умолчанию не обращается к переменной через свойство. Код в set выполнится только при явном вызове свойства Val.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался !